# Timespan in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timespan

I'm writing an asp.net mvc app. in c#, and I'm wondering if anybody can help me to understand, if it's possible to display the time like 8:00 (without seconds) on the form in a dropdown list instead of 8:00:00. Thanks for your help!

Right now I have a code in my timehepler.cs:

```
public static List<TimeSpan> TimeSpansInRange(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            List<TimeSpan> timeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
            while (start.Add(interval) <= end)
            {
                timeSpans.Add(start);
                start = start.Add(interval);
            }
            return timeSpans;
        }

        public static List<TimeSpan> PossibleTimeSpansInDay()
        {
            return TimeSpansInRange(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
        }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately that limits things - .NET 4 has better TimeSpan formatting support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the List Type to String and then while adding convert it to the format you required unfortunately there is no alternative of it except converting the result to string as much i know....

```
   public static List<string> TimeSpansInRange(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        List<string> timeSpans = new List<string>();
        while (start.Add(interval) <= end)
        {
            timeSpans.Add(start.Hours.ToString() +":"+start.Minutes.ToString());
            start = start.Add(interval);
        }
        return timeSpans;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the List Type to String and then in the next statement

Comment: public static List<TimeSpan> PossibleTimeSpansInDay()
        {
            return TimeSpansInRange(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
        }
I also changed it to string. 
But the next TimeSpan that is not the List Type: 
public static TimeSpan NextPossibleTimeSpan()
        {
            return PossibleTimeSpansInDay().Where(t => t > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(new TimeSpan(0,15,0))).FirstOrDefault();
        } gives me an error message
What am I missing here? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Daug: Sorry for the late reply i was busy, First you made a static method with return type List<TimeSpan> for this you have to use TimeSpan.Parse(string val) then this will work but it will again add seconds which you don't want use List<string> this will work. In the second code snippet you are comparing a date with a list which is wrong way but you can do this by using Foreach loop .see my updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use ToString like the control is probably doing.

Instead, convert it to a string yourself with

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
   private static string ConvertTimeSpanToString (this TimeSpan myTimeSpan)
   {
      return (int) myTimeSpan.TotalHours + ":" + myTimeSpan.Minutes.ToString("00");
   }
}
```

You'll call it this way:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Start", Model.Request.StartTimes.Select(TimeSpanExtensions.ConvertTimeSpanToString) %> 
<%= Html.DropDownList("End", Model.Request.EndTimes.Select(TimeSpanExtensions.ConvertTimeSpanToString) %>
```

In .net 4, you could probably just use a format string in your listbox.  `myTimeSpan.ToString ("HH:mm");` when you display the time.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to show the time like 8:00 without seconds?

Comment: @Jon Skeet.  Good catch.  @Greg, here's a new sloppier answer: convert it to a string with your own code.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have a dropdown list on the form and the code is <%= Html.DropDownList("Start", Model.Request.StartTimes %> <%= Html.DropDownList("End", Model.Request.EndTimes %>. Where exactly should I use your code? Thank you so much for your help?

Comment: @Greg, `Model.Request.EndTimes.Select (t => ConvertTimeSpanToString(t))`

Comment: I tried to change the code as you suggested but i get an error CS0103: The name 'ConvertTimeSpanToString' does not exist in the current context. What am doing doing wrong here? so grateful for your help!

Comment: You have to create a method called ConvertTimeSpanToString, but it can just return the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try, looks like this is not trivial